# How do you write a operator() or less-than-functor neater than a trivalue-compare-function

Tags: c++, stl

Writing an operator< () for a struct appears to be clearer than writing the classical trivalue compare.

for example, to sort the following

```
struct S {
    int val;
};
```

you can write an **operator<** ()

```
bool operator< ( const S &l, const S &r ) {
     return l.val < r.val;
}
```

or, a **trivalue** function (*usually in the following fashion* )

```
int compare( const S &l, const S &r ) {
    if( r.val > l.val ) return 1;
    if( r.val < l.val ) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

The former is clearer, therefore you can say there's better code quality.
The latter forces you to think of 3 cases, which complicates code.

But this thought is a bit deceiving in more complex structures:

```
struct S {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

the following is clear, and begginners tend to write it like so

```
bool operator< ( const S &l, const S &r ) {
     if( l.x < r.x ) return true;
     if( l.y < r.y ) return true;
     return false;
}
```

but it's **wrong** !  You can't sort correctly with this !

And it takes some time to think that
you actually have to write it like so

```
bool operator< ( const S &l, const S &r ) {
     if( l.x < r.x ) return true;
     if( l.x > r.x ) return false;
     if( l.y < r.y ) return true;
     if( l.y > r.y ) return false;
     return false;
}
```

for it to work correctly.

*Can you, and **do you** write this sort of compare function in a nicer/clearer manner ?* 
The old trivalue compare function at least 'forced' you into thinking about >, <, and == cases.

Comment: i don't see any difference between the last two operator< functions.

Comment: @Donotalo: Then look more carefully.

Comment: to test how it fails, make a set<S>, add a few (~30) x-y pairs in, it, making sure that some are duplicates. Then print the size of the set. Do it for both versions of the operator< () above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that you are fine with just declaring one trivalue compare function if you autogenerate all operators using: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick

Comment: +1, Very reminiscent of Haskell. This would also have been my advice.

Comment: You don't need a trivalue comparison function to generate all the operators, it just requires combining two comparisons.

Comment: @Mark You need three values to generate `<,>,<=,>=,==,!=`

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Sorry, I was trying to say if you have `<` or `>` you can generate all six.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: it's called `boost::less_than_comparable` from Boost.Operators. Very handy, but doesn't solve the issue of writing a proper `operator<` in the first place.

Comment: @Matthieu Well with the original Barton-Nackman trick you don't write any operators. Just a trivalue compare method.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: I don't understand what you mean. Whether you write `operator<` or `cmp` is still writing a method that you need to get right, and both are of equal complexity...

Comment: @Matthieu Ugh, this is the second time in this thread of comments. You need three values to generate all operators, therefore implementing just `operator<` is not enough! That's the whole point of my answer. You are fine with just one method that returns 3 values. From that you can auto-generate all the comparison/equality operators using the Barton-Nackman trick.

Comment: @Let_Me_be: no, `operator<` is enough. `lhs > rhs` as `rhs < lhs`, `lhs <= rhs` as `!(rhs < lhs)` and `lhs >= rhs` as `!(lhs < rhs)`. You also have `lhs == rhs` as `!(lhs < rhs) && !(rhs < lhs)` and `lhs != rhs` as `lhs < rhs || rhs < lhs`. May have gotten some wrong, but that's the gist of the reasoning. And that's what Boost.Operators use (and Boost.Operators works, really, and uses the Barton-Nackman trick).

Comment: @Matthieu OK, yes, if you are fine with more then one comparison being done, then yes, you are fine with just `operator<`.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: note that the two comparisons only occurs with `==` and `!=` and that writing `cmp` might be a pessimization if you actually need two comparisons to define it, that will then always be used :) Also, because of this pessimization, Boost.Operators normally require `==` to be defined separately and does not infer it from `<`, it does infer `!=` from `==` though.

Answer (score 5):

If I don't care about performance or compiler spew, I tend to use this:

```
return make_tuple(l.x, l.y, ...) < make_tuple(r.x, r.y, ...);
```

And for a slightly less expensive in terms of copies version:

```
return tie(cref(l.x), cref(l.y), ...) < tie(cref(r.x), cref(r.y), ...);
```

Incidentally, the second version also works with lvalues.

Comment: Interesting idea. But wouldn't `return tie(l.x, l.y, ...) < tie(r.x, r.y, ...);` avoid a copy? (I assume this creates tuples of references).

Comment: @UncleBens... holy crap, I didn't think of that! I guess my initial disclaimer was even worse than I thought :) Although it doesn't work if l or r are or contain const values.

Comment: Seems to compile for me (GCC 4.3): it creates const references.

Comment: +1 for UncleBens comment :) Do include it in your answer, it certainly is the best way!

Comment: @UncleBens, on VC8, it barfs saying none of the two overloads could convert all the argument types. :(

Comment: @MSN: I don't have VC8 handy, have you tested with `make_tuple(cref(l.x), cref(l.y), ...)` ?

Comment: I actually did this with a member function call, not a member. `tie(l.x)<tie(r.x)` works fine, but `tie(l.x())<tie(r.x())` does not. @Matthieu, yes, `adding std::ref(...)` makes `make_tuple` work without making copies.

Comment: @MSN: I would really use `cref` here, `l` and `r` are probably `const` qualified (or should) and thus you'll need the const-ness.

Comment: @Matthieu, @UncleBens, turns out I forgot to `#include <functional>`, so now the original version works even with lvalues :)

Answer (score 4):

I like to do it like this:

```
bool operator< ( const S &l, const S &r )
{
    if( l.x != r.x ) return l.x < r.x;
    else return l.y < r.y;
}
```

EDIT: note that this is also one useful feature of `std::pair` too - it defines this already so you can't make the mistake.

Answer (score 4):

In the `int` case you can simply write:

```
return l.x < r.x || (l.x == r.x && l.y < r.y);
```

Only of you are talking about a type that doesn't have `==` with the correct behaviour do you need to use something more complex, even then it's not too bad.

```
return l.x < r.x || (!(r.x < l.x) && l.y < r.y);
```

Extending to more members:

```
return l.x < r.x ||
      !(r.x < l.x) && (l.y < r.y ||
      !(r.y < l.y) && (l.z < r.z ||
      /* ... */
      ) /* lisp-like sequence of ) */ );
```

If you can arrange your members to be in an array or other container you can use `std::lexicographical_compare`.

Comment: hmm, I like the lexicographical_compare idea !!

Answer (score 1):

This is no clearer or shorter than your last example, but it does have the advantage of not requiring anything other than `operator<` on the members.

```
bool operator< ( const S &l, const S &r ) { 
     if( l.x < r.x ) return true; 
     if( r.x < l.x ) return false; 
     if( l.y < r.y ) return true; 
     if( r.y < l.y ) return false; 
     return false; 
}
```

The last case can always be simplified, unfortunately the prior cases must always be the longer form.

```
bool operator< ( const S &l, const S &r ) { 
     if( l.x < r.x ) return true; 
     if( r.x < l.x ) return false; 
     return  l.y < r.y; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I did once which seemed a useful idiom was to write a compare function which returns a boolean given takes two arguments plus a boolean called "bias".  The function returns true if the first argument is greater, or if "bias" is set and the two arguments are equal.  Thus, a compare whose result depended upon two sub-comparisons would be:

```
  if (compare(a.part1,b.part1,compare(a.part2,b.part2,bias)))
    ...
```

Note that this will do 'extra' comparisons, since part2's will be compared even if the part1 compare would be sufficient to yield an answer, but if avoids redundant tests for equality.

Otherwise, using tri-value logic, one could do something like:

```
  int result;

  if ((result = compare(a.part1,b.part1)) != 0) return result;
  if ((result = compare(a.part2,b.part2)) != 0) return result;
```

The latter form avoids unnecessary comparisons, and is easily extensible to any number of fields.

Answer (score 0):

For the first **tri-value** `compare()` function

```
int compare( const S &l, const S &r ) {
    return r.val - l.val;
}
```

For the later

```
bool operator< ( const S &l, const S &r ) {
     return (l.x < r.x) || ((l.x == r.x) && (l.y < r.y));
}
```

Comment: The tri-value version cannot be used in the general case, because the result may under- or overflow.